# Jackson XML - deserializing empty classes and polymorphism

Tags: java, xml, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

I have the following interface:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EmptyProxy.class, name = "empty"),
        ... other types not included ...
})
public interface Proxy {
}
```

I have the following implementation:

```
@JsonTypeName("empty")
public static class EmptyProxy implements Proxy {
}
```

As you can see, it is just an empty class. I left the other (working) implementations out of this example.

I have the following container data class:

```
public static class Data {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
    private String name;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "proxy")
    private Proxy  proxy;
}
```

Deserializing `EmptyProxy` does not seem to work. For example:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper().registerModule(new JacksonXmlModule());
final Data data = mapper.readValue("<data><name>my-name</name><proxy><empty/></proxy></data>", Data.class);
```

This gives the following exeption:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of Test$EmptyProxy out of VALUE_NULL token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@59ec2012; line: 1, column: 42] (through reference chain: Data["proxy"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:857)
```

Is this a bug in Jackson? FWIW, when I add a dummy field to `EmptyProxy`, it works.

**update**

I tried with JAXB only, and get the same result. Code:

```
public static class Data {
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(type = EmptyProxy.class, name = "empty")
    })
    private Proxy  proxy;
}

public interface Proxy {
}

@XmlType(name = "empty")
public static class EmptyProxy implements Proxy {
}

public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper()/*.registerModule(new JacksonXmlModule())*/.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    final Data data = mapper.readValue("<data><name>my-name</name><proxy><empty></empty></proxy></data>", Data.class);
}
```

Comment: I also created a bug report: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a bug entry for this. See http://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/169.